# Div tag getAttribute not working when inside li tag contains other html tags in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am wondering the problem of getting the getAttribute div html.

```
<ul id="_listus">
    <li data-value="name1">Name 1</li>
    <li data-value="name2">Name 2</li>
</ul>
<input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
```

**When the `li` tag clicks I proceed to get the data: `data-value`**

```
$("#_listus").on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    const domIndex = e.target.getAttribute('data-value');
    $('#hdId').val(domIndex);
    
});
```

**-----> It gets valid results**

However when I change my html to:

```
<ul id="_listus">
    <li data-value="name1"><div class="class1">Name 1</div></li>
    <li data-value="name2"><div class="class1">Name 2</div></li>
</ul>
<input id="hdId" type="hidden" />
```

**-------> When the li tag clicks, I get `null`. Why????????????**

I don't think when changing the html content in the `<li>...</li>` tag. It doesn't get the `getAttribute` from the `<li>` tag on click. Looking forward to hearing from everyone. Thank you!

Comment: Because you _are_ clicking on the div element, so that's what `e.target` will be now. Use `currentTarget` instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event#instance_properties

Comment: In addition to @CBroe comment you can also do it the jQuery way like `$(this).data('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.target` is not a trusted object. Read more:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target

Use `event.currentTarget`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

```js
$("#_listus").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  const domIndex = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-value');
  $('#hdId').val(domIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="_listus">
  <li data-value="name1">
    <div class="class1">Name 1</div>
  </li>
  <li data-value="name2">
    <div class="class1">Name 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<input id="hdId" />
```

Comment: @Yogi `event.target` will point to the object that caused the event, not the object to which the event was attached. that means `event.target` can return `null`!

Comment: @TachibanaShin The problem lies here. Thank you very much!